# Asus Vivo PC and Ubuntu installation Problem

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, asus

Bought a new pc couple of days ago, Asus Vivo Pc V60. Downloaded 14.04 LTS 64bit version, after installation, it goes to a black screen with a bunch of error messages, and fatal error and lots os random letters and numbers..

My old dual core pc runs Ubuntu 14.04 just fine.. What did a do wrong, should i try the 32bit version?

Thank You

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvm5ichp2iiu9ma/2014-07-03%2023.22.26.jpg

image link added

Comment: You should post screenshots of your errors

Comment: This seems to be fixed in 14.10 and betas are out now. At least once I got past secure boot I was able to set up dual booting and get a useable system. Hope this helps.

Comment: try turning of WLAN in the bios

Answer (score 0):

I have dual boot running fine on my VivoPc v60, the only issue is the darn clock in Windows changing every time you go to change boot order via BIOS/UEFI.

To sidestep that I use a bcdedit script that moves Ubuntu to the head of the boot order in Windows and then in Ubuntu you need to reboot and select Windows Boot Manager from Grub. Efibootmgr doesn't seem to work at all from Ubuntu.

Anyhow back to why I posted. I originally bought the vivo because of the UTube videos showing how easy it was to swap HDs. Of course that was made more difficult in the V60 which uses a notebook size HD and locks the lid with a screw. Opening the lid voids warranty etc...

Anyhow I popped in an old notebook HD a couple of days ago installed via Live USB and rebooted to what I can only assume is what you saw. I still have no idea why that happened..

Comment: image link added.no idea what to do :s